# How can I embed Split View controller in Tab Bar controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I started with a Master-Detail Application, then went to the **iPhone** `storyboard`, selected the `NavigationController` and went to **Editor** > **Embed In** > `TabBarController` and it worked just fine. When I tried to do the same in the **iPad** `storyboard` the Embed in `TabBarController` menu item was disabled. Should I just do that manually?

Answer (score 7):

1. Create a sample Master/Detail via xcode
2. Drag a tabViewController on the storyboard
3. Change the TabViewController to the initial view controller.
4. Control Drag from the TabViewController to the SplitViewControler
5. Assign a title to the SplitViewControler in the storyboard (I Used "Master"
6. In the app delegate replace the reference to the splitViewController as follows.

   ```
   let tabBarViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
   print(tabBarViewController.viewControllers?.count)
   var splitViewController:UISplitViewController? = nil
   for viewController in tabBarViewController.viewControllers! {
       if viewController.title == "Master" {
           splitViewController = viewController as? UISplitViewController
       }
   }

   let navigationController = splitViewController!.viewControllers[splitViewController!.viewControllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController
   navigationController.topViewController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController!.displayModeButtonItem()
   splitViewController!.delegate = self
   ```

Comment: Thanks Rob! This is exactly what I needed for my own project!

Answer (score 1):

In my application I embed programmatically like below

```
        UISplitViewController *split=[[UISplitViewController alloc]init];
        PatientListController *patListContr=[[PatientListController alloc]init];
        PatientController *patientControl=[[PatientController alloc]init];
        split.viewControllers=@[patListContr,patientControl];
        split.tabBarItem=[[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"patient.png"] selectedImage:nil];
```

Then embed the above split view controller to a TabbarController

```
UITabBarController *tabbarContr=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];
        tabbarContr.viewControllers=@[split,yourController1,yourController2];
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Rob George's Swift answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35564833/2875404), here is the Objective-C code:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarViewController= (UITabBarController *) self.window.rootViewController;
NSLog(@"%lu",tabBarViewController.viewControllers.count);
UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)nil;

for(UIViewController *viewController in tabBarViewController.viewControllers){
    if([viewController.title isEqualToString:@"Master"]){
        splitViewController= (UISplitViewController *) viewController;
    }
}

UINavigationController *navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1];
navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;
splitViewController.delegate = self;
```

Took me a while because "first" ViewController was white and with the bar (with no icons and white text) being almost perfectly white, too, I thought the app just defaults to displaying nothing but actually it was picking the ViewController that was empty and I simply didn't see the bar. Just in case you were wondering why it doesn't work lol

Answer (score 0):

The Split View Controller can't be embedded into anything - it needs to be the root view controller in your storyboard.

You can however select either the Master View Controller or the Detail View Controller and embed those classes into other view controllers.

Comment: this is not true, you can certainly use a splitview controller as a tab item in a tabbar controller, doesnt have to be the root vc.